# Is there a way to be notified of top questions across Stack Exchange platforms, such as in a weekly digest?

Tags: support, notifications, newsletter

I am a part of many Stack Exchange sites, which I love - and I would like to receive a weekly email with the top questions from each site.

I know that I can subscribe to specific topics, such as 'react' on StackOverflow and 'phrases' in english.stackexchange.com but that's tedious and limits my visibility to those topics.

Maybe that's the point - it's too overwhelming without some type of filter and I should just create high level filters.

Apologies if this has been asked, I couldn't find it - and thanks for all the fish StackExchange.

Comment: Here is a similar feature request: [Offer a network-wide newsletter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100263). (It is from 2011 - it seems it did not get much attention, it has 62 views and score +5 at the moment.)

Comment: Another request, for a *complete* Newsletter, has a better reception: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247298/282094 but wasn't implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! You can subscribe to digests for any community at https://stackexchange.com/digests

For example, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/digest/preview) is a preview of this week’s digest for Meta Stack Exchange, and here are [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/digest/preview), [Super User](https://superuser.com/digest/preview), and [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/digest/preview).

You can also subscribe to a community’s digest from the [“Community digests” page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/digests/current) in your profile on that community.